# $\sqrt{3-\sqrt5}+\sqrt{3+\sqrt5}$

Tags: radicals

$$\sqrt{3-\sqrt5}+\sqrt{3+\sqrt5}$$
I'm trying to get the term
$$\sqrt{x\pm2\sqrt y}$$
However, I don't know how to.

Comment: Why are there so many radical questions appearing today?

Comment: Hint: $\;a^2+b^2=6, ab=2$, then $a+b=\ldots$

Comment: $3-\sqrt 5=\frac{6-2\sqrt 5}2$

Comment: What do you mean with "I'm trying to get the term $\sqrt{x \pm 2\sqrt y}$"?

Answer (score 7):

Set $$x=\sqrt{3-\sqrt5}+\sqrt{3+\sqrt5}$$
and square both sides to obtain
$$x^2=(3-\sqrt5)+2\sqrt{(3-\sqrt5)(3+\sqrt5)}+(3+\sqrt5)$$
$$x^2=6+2\sqrt{9-5}=6+4=10$$
$$x=\sqrt{10},$$
since clearly $x>0$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\sqrt{3+\sqrt5}=\frac1{\sqrt2}\sqrt{6+2\sqrt5}=\frac{1+\sqrt5}{\sqrt2}$ and $\sqrt{3-\sqrt5}=\frac{-1+\sqrt5}{\sqrt2}$,$$\sqrt{3+\sqrt5}+\sqrt{3-\sqrt5}=\frac{2\sqrt5}{\sqrt2}=\sqrt{10}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt {{3}-\sqrt 5{}} +\sqrt {{3}+\sqrt 5{}} = \sqrt {{\frac52+\frac12}-2\sqrt {\frac52 \frac12}{}} +\sqrt {{\frac52+\frac12}+2\sqrt {\frac52 \frac12}{}} \\ = |\sqrt\frac52 - \sqrt\frac12| + |\sqrt\frac52 + \sqrt\frac12| = \sqrt{10}$$